# Changing KML markers/Icons in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: google-earth-pro

How to change KML markers/Icons in Google Earth Pro?

I have put in all of the paths that I could find on kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html#notes?

I am not understanding the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

In a KML file, the Icon used by a point placemark can either be defined via an inline style, in the Placemark itself, or it can be in a shared style that each placemark refers to via a styleUrl tag.  In either case, the tags to define the icon style will look something like this:

```
<Style id="mystyle">
  <IconStyle>
    <scale>1.3</scale>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://example.com/path/icon.jpg</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

If you're editing the KML by hand or programatically you can find where the icons styles are currently defined (inline or shared), and just swap out the URLs inside the ... tags.

If you're editing the KML using Google Earth Pro, then you can either edit each placemark individually, or go to the container (Folder or Document) tell it to use a shared style for all placemarks inside it, and define the icon once at that level.

To edit the icon for a Placemark in Earth, right-click on the placemark (on the map or the Places list), select "Properties" ("Get Info" on Mac), and then click on the Icon button (to the right of the Name field).  That will bring up the icon dialog, where you can select an icon from the list, or Add a custom Icon using the buttons at the bottom.  If you want to do it at the Folder level, right-click the Folder, select Properties (or Get Info), and go to the Style,Color tab. There you should see a Share Styles button which will make the styles for everything in that folder the same.  Then use the icon button to select the icon.

For a tutorial that walks you through some of these steps, try this:
https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/annotating-google-earth/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like each icon should have its own path in Google Earth. For example the path for the yellow pushpin is as shown below.

**http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png**

This is the path you would have to add if you did not have it and you wanted to add or change, i.e add the specific name of the icon you are interested in to the end of the path as shown.

The list of paths on the site are links within the same document to help navigate the page.

You could also save icons to you device files and access them with paths pointing to them.